# Trying to access and edit an unassigned element in a special Array with Assembly

Tags: c#, assembly, qvector3d

I am working on this 3d based program, I got stumped midway through this assembly script as to how I could assign a new value to a new Instance of an array's unassigned  element.

```
.data
x DB 00000000b
y DB 00000000b
z DB 00000000b
Vector3 DT OFFSET x
        DT OFFSET y
        DT OFFSET z
bName DB "Brick"
TypeName DT ?
clickD DB 00000000b
checkV DB 00000001b
NOP
.code
main proc
returnD:
MOV AH, checkV
CMP AH, clickD
JNE returnD
CALL clickEvent
JMP returnD
main endp
clickEvent proc
makeB:
Brick DT OFFSET [Vector3]
      DT OFFSET [TypeName]
RET
clickEvent endp
END
NOP
```

The Array I am trying to work with is the 'Brick' array, in which I am trying to assign its unassigned element 'TypeName' to the 'bName' value specified in .data. The real issue is the fact that the 'Brick' array must only be created when clickD is equal to 1. (1 meant as 'true' in this case to determine when a user clicks on a button to create a new Brick) I need to be able to change Brick's TypeName Value to the bName value on creation of a brick array, and I honestly have no clue how to do this. I have thought the solution may involve doing something like MOVing the value of bName into a register and MOVing the register's value into the brick's typeName Address, which may be able to be stored as a variable, but I am not sure how I could do this. Another possibility may involve pushing bName onto the data stack, and perhaps pushing Bricks typename element onto the stack and MOVing data from there, then poping the data back, but again, the type of array that brick is makes it seem more difficult to do so. I am using x86, masm Assembly, with an Athlon processor, if that helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please clarify what kind of C# help you are looking for?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are up to, but `CALL clickEvent` doesn't create a new Brick, it tries to execute the data as code. All the `DB` and `DT` are created at compile time, nothing is dynamic or created at runtime.

Comment: oh, well then that changes everything. My previous understanding of Define directives was that they would execute on run-time, or wherever they were used in a program. Perhaps I could make a Brick in the .data segment, and from there when clickEvent is executing, somehow copy the brick inside data, and paste a clone of it into the data stack. Thanks you so much!

Comment: @alexei, once I finish the 'heart' of the project, I plan on switching to C# to create advanced interfaces, and adding in some lua to go through some UI events. The entire project is going to be a 3d based studio.